# wanted to limit the looping while using ForEach

Tags: java

Say I got 100 records from DB, I want to loop 10 times and perform some action.
and loop again and perform some action.. it continues until the last record is read.

The problem what i am seeing is

```
for (int number: numbers) {
    add(number);
    //after adding 10 items I want to complete a function and continue the loop
}
```

But here in Java, if use the above loop we can see it will iterate the complete list and comes out.

I know in older versions, we can iterate by counter like

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
```

some thing like this.

My question is if `forEach` loop doesnot provide this flexibility, then why Sun Java introduced to a looping mechanism where it will iterate completely.

Trying to understand the logic of this design.

Comment: You can declare a counter variable outside the loop, but it is best to use an index-based loop in this case to reduce variable scope.

Comment: "For each loop" - try to read it out loud. What does "for each" mean in your opinion?

Comment: You can still write `for(int i=0; i<10;i++)`. It wasn't removed or deprecated or anything.

Comment: Because you're using the wrong construct for what you're trying to do. The enhanced `for` (that's what it's called) is used for other purposes. For what you need to do just use the classic `for` loop. It's not like it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a forEach or for-in with a nested conditional.

```
for(number: numbers){
     if(number != (multOfTen)){
        
         myFunction(number);
         add(number);
    
     }else{

          add(number);

     }
}
```

you will need to replace `multOfTen` w/ an expression that includes only multiples of ten.
One way to do this is to use regEx to check that the last digit is zero (so long as your using integers.)

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, `forEach` will iterate over the whole collection. This is the same for JavaScript and several other languages. However you can abort / skip the iteration with a condition (which depends on the language implementation details).

Answer (score 2):

There are difference between `for` and `forEach` loop. There are reason why java has these 2. `forEach` is enhance for loop. Both have their usage based on requirements.

`for`

This we can use for general purpose. This is totally based on indexes. If you want to play with data at particular index or want to perform some actions based on index of element, you should use `for`.

`forEach`

this is used with only collections and arrays. This iterate over whole collections at once. Means you can't have index of element while iterating it. This is used when you manipulate each data in list regardless whats its index. For example to print all element in a given list, instead of writing classical `for` loop

```
for (int i =0; i < list.length(); i++){

  System.out.println(list(i));

}
```

we use `forEach` loop

```
list.forEach(e -> {
      System.out.println(e);
});
```

this is more readable, easy to use and crisp.

Comment: They're not asking about the `forEach` method, they're asking about the enhanced `for` (which in some languages, e.g. php, is called `foreach`).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried to answer the part where he asked "My question is if forEach loop doesnot provide this flexibility, then why Sun Java introduced to a looping mechanism where it will iterate completely.

Trying to understand the logic of this design." 

I apologise If I answer it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

because sometimes the question or the implementation you're doing using `java` doesn't need the index of the array "simply".

so instead of writing the whole `for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)` thing you can just use `foreach` and instead of `arr[i]` you use a simple variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible using the same Stream api but it's beyond the scope of forEach. What you want to do isn't possible by limiting yourself to forEach. The purpose of forEach is to execute some action without bias on all elements of an Iterable or Stream. What you can do is break down your objects into groups of 10 and then for each grouping of 10, do what you want which is add all to the underlying collection and then perform some other action which is what you want as well.

```java
        List<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0, 100)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        int batch = 10; 

        List<List<Integer>> groupsOfTen = IntStream.range(0, values.size() / batch + 1)
                .map(index -> index * batch)
                .mapToObj(index -> values.subList(index,
                        Math.min(index + batch, values.size())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        groupsOfTen.forEach(myListOfTen -> myListOfTen.forEach(individual -> {
            
        }));
```